# R Shiny: Use function default values when fields are left blank in app

Tags: r, shiny

I have an R Shiny app and I'd like to have it automatically use the default values for the function that is called by Shiny when the fields are left blank in the Shiny App. I'm providing a simple example where the Shiny App is calling the function `printFun`. I want this to work so that if, for example, a user does not put in a value for `b` in the Shiny app, the function would recognize this to be interpreted as `2`, the default value. However, if you leave `b` blank, it will not pass any value to the function.

Are there any options to deal with defaults like this in Shiny? Thanks in advance for your help.

```
library(shiny)
# simple example of function
printFun <- function(a = 1, b =2, c =3, d = 4){
  printVal <- paste0(
    "one = ", a, "\n",
    "two = ", b, "\n",
    "three = ", c, "\n",
    "four = ", d, "\n"
  )
  cat(printVal)
}

# ui function
ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("a", "a value"),
  textInput("b", "b value"),
  textInput("c", "c value"),
  textInput("d", "d value"),
  actionButton("runFun", "run function")
)

# server function
server <- function(input, output){
  observeEvent(input$runFun, {
    printFun(
      a=input$a,
      b=input$b,
      c=input$c,
      d=input$d
    )
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach

```
server <- function(input, output){
  observeEvent(input$runFun, {
    vals <- Map(function(x) input[[x]], c("a","b","c","d"))
    vals <- Map(as.numeric, vals)
    vals <- Filter(function(x) !is.na(x), vals)
    do.call("printFun", vals)
  })
}
```

Basically we `Map` to get all the values and turn them into numbers. Then we Filter out the values that aren't numbers. We need to do this because you have text inputs and when those are empty you probably want to ignore them. So now we have a list of user supplied values that we can pass to the function with `do.call`.

You could also add in the defaults to the text inputs themselves.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("a", "a value", value=formals(printFun)[["a"]]),
  textInput("b", "b value", value=formals(printFun)[["b"]]),
  textInput("c", "c value", value=formals(printFun)[["c"]]),
  textInput("d", "d value", value=formals(printFun)[["d"]]),
  actionButton("runFun", "run function")
)
```

Comment: This is great. I like the second option better, which also answers the question "How can I automatically populate input values in a shiny app?"

Answer (score 1):

How about a helper function, because Shiny is passing empty strings:

```
printFun <- function(a, b, c, d){
  useDef <- function(a,d) ifelse(isTruthy(a), a,d) 
  printVal <- paste0(
    "one = ", useDef(a,1), "\n",
    "two = ",useDef(b,2), "\n",
    "three = ", useDef(c,3), "\n",
    "four = ", useDef(d,4), "\n"
  )
  cat(printVal)
}
```